# Castle Windsor & Registering ApplicationContext

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm trying to register ApplicationContext, but keep getting an error.

My Windsor Installer looks like this:

```
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(

            Component.For<ApplicationContext>().ImplementedBy<MyInitializer>(),

            Classes.FromThisAssembly().Pick()
                    .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
                    .LifestyleTransient()
            );
    }
```

But, when trying to resolve it like this:

```
public class BootStrapperWindsor
{
    public IWindsorContainer BootstrapContainer { get; set; }
    public ApplicationContext ApplicationContext
    {
        get { return BootstrapContainer.Resolve<MyInitializer>(); }
    }

    public BootStrapperWindsor()
    {
         BootstrapContainer = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());
    }
}
```

I get this error when calling ApplicationContext:

"No component for supporting the service MyInitializer was found"

It works fine when I used structuremap and made a similar association in my structuremap registry:

```
For<ApplicationContext>().Use<MyInitializer>();
```

But, I can't seem to convert this over to Windsor correctly.

What am I doing wrong that I can't implement the ApplicationContext with MyInitializer?

Also, MyInitializer inherits from ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`container.Resolve< ApplicationContext>()` is what you want.

Comment: Derp on my part.  Thanks for catching that.